# Remove Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 header from Response headers

Tags: iis, http-headers, httpresponse, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have IIS 8.5 installed on my Windows server 2012 R2. I am trying to remove the Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 header from my responses.

I tried installed URLScan but it fails to install with the following error

```
IIS Metabase is required to install Microsoft URLScan Filter v3.1.
```

I have tried to remove it from the UrlRewrite settings on my website but it's not working. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a custom module to clean my headers inside the app:

```
public class HeadersCleanupModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostReleaseRequestState += application_PostReleaseRequestState;
    }


    void application_PostReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("ETag");
    }


}
```

Comment: You put it in global.asax?

Comment: I put it in root directory of my web project and register the module in Web.config: 

`<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HeadersCleanupModule" type="WebApp.HeadersCleanupModule" />
    </modules>`